# iframe in - rewrite results - Override the output of this field with custom text

Tags: views, blocks

I'm trying to make a view for showing latest youtube videos in a block

I have a field called Youtube Video ID (Plain text) where I Drupal 8 stores the ID of the video...

I'm using the option of the field "Override the output of this field with custom text" in REWRITE RESULTS...

I'm doing something like this:

```
<div class='embed-container-youtube'>
<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ field_id_video_de_youtube__value }}' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Like you can see.. I'm using that mark up to show a youtube video.. taking the value of the field....

the problem is that Drupal is cleaning the iframe mark up.. I think for security...

this is how Drupal render it in the website

```
<div class="embed-container-youtube">

</div>
```

When you configure the content type you can see a note:

```
Allowed HTML tags: <a> <b> <big> <code> <del> <em> <i> <ins> <pre> <q> <small> <span> <strong> <sub> <sup> <tt> <ol> <ul> <li> <p> <br> <img>
This field supports tokens.
```

how can I add more allowed tags?

How can I allow that HTML tag for this view?
¡Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been wrestling with this as well but my users want to embed google docs.  Same concept though.

I figured out the solution and it's not super complicated.  You you just need to create a 'Field Template' in the theme.

This video covers the concept with 'Node Template' but you can easily apply it to the field template.

Drupal 8 Theming - Part 11 - Displaying Fields
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQ6Ypik_jsE

Comment: I tried to create an override for the template:
``core/modules/block/templates/block.html.twig``
in ``themes/my_theme/templates/block--views-block--ultimos-videos-block-1.html.twig``

but I cant print tags like this:
``{{ content.field_id_video_de_youtube }}``

The only available tag is ``{{ content}}``

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this by including the entire iframe in the field and displaying the field as is. I avoided rewriting it anyway with views, no rewrite results or using a custom text field.

It's not ideal and means more CSS but at least the iframes are in the view.

Answer (score -2):

It's been a while since this question has been asked, but in case someone searches for a solution for this problem and ends up here (like I did):

You can add the iframe-Tag to the Xss whitelist:

- Open the file core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Xss.php
- Add 'iframe' to the $adminTags array

After refreshing the cache, iframe-Tags will no longer be stripped from your override text.

Comment: Don't do this, it will break next time when you update Drupal.